# Write (new) pandas DF to sql with different number of columns

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

So I have a DF that's been written to SQL:

```
dbWrite = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:pass@1.1.1.1:3306/myDb')
df0.to_sql('table', con=dbWrite, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

So far, so good.

Now, in the mean time, I do build a new `df1`, which is basically identical to `df0` but for some minor differences: some rows can be modified in their content and a new column is added. The rest of the columns are identical, both in names and content. New indexes (rows) can be added.

If I proceed as above, I get this error: `InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'newColumn' in 'field list'")`, which is understandable: `df0` had `N` columns and `df1` has `N+1` columns.

If I do a `df1.to_sql('table', con=dbWrite, if_exists='replace', index=True)`, then the table at the MySQL server gets removed, a new one is created, and the DataFrame is finally stored. But this is inconvenient: with the `replace` keyword, old values are removed and lost.

I've thought of doing something like:

```
try:
    df1.to_sql('table', con=dbWrite, if_exists='append', index=True)
except:
    tempDf = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table', dbWrite).set_index('objectId')
    df1 = pd.concat([df1,tempDf])
    df1.to_sql('table', con=dbWrite, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

... but after the concat I do get as twice as rows, and many duplicate values. Most of the rows are identical but for the new column.

In summary: which would be the appropriate way of only uploading the differences between `df0` (already on the mysql server) and `df1`, the new DF?

Thanks!

Comment: it would be better if you write a stored procedure that can infer the schema from a staging table then union both the new and old tables as a new one. or even better you can write to a schema table so you can infer it manually with each dB write. this method is messy & potentially risky.

Comment: Can you not just make a 2nd table with `df1.to_sql('table_2', con=dbWrite, if_exists='append', index=True)` or is there a reason you need the results in the same table?

Comment: @Matt, well I could use a 2nd table, but that would not scale: I'll be constantly duplicating information for every new table to be uploaded. I just want to upload the differences between what's already stored in the DB and my new DF ... this will be a routine that will be run every certain period ... On the other hand, since this is a table that stores inventory and assets, I prefer that there will be only one table ...

Comment: So, I've been reading a bit and I guess that I need a schema-less DB. I'll try with MongoDB instead ... I think it would fit me better for my needs ...